# Why does sklearn cross_validate() refit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I understand why a tool like [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) refits. It explores over a range of hyperparameter values and after comparing scores, refits an estimator using the best found parameters on the whole dataset.

But whilst that makes sense, my question is about the [cross_validate](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) class where only a single set of hyperparameters is used. my undestanding of the purpose for which is to see how well the model generalises over different folds of train/test splits. Why is a refit used here?

I understand why n fits happen on the n folds of data. But according to the documentation, a refit also happens, as discussed in the `error_score` parameter:

> error_score : ‘raise’ or numeric Value
>
> > to assign to the score if an error occurs in estimator fitting. If set to ‘raise’, the error is raised. If a numeric value is given, FitFailedWarning is raised. This parameter does not affect the refit step, which will always raise the error.

So on top of the n fits, there is an extra fit and I don't understand why this happens. There is no predict method for this class so even if it somehow differentiated between models and selected a 'best' one (despite them all having the exact same hyperparameters), there is no point in refitting.

To demonstrate this, I created a MLPRegressor model that I knew, combined with my dataset would have exploding gradients:

```py
DL = MLPRegressor(
        hidden_layer_sizes=(200, 200, 200), activation='relu', max_iter=16,
            solver='sgd', learning_rate='invscaling', power_t=0.9)
DL.fit(df_training[predictor_cols], df_training[target_col])
```

The model fits without error (proving there are no NaN or inf values in my dataset) but does give the warning:

> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in matmul

This evidences the exploding gradient and the output of any predictions is therefore NaN.

From my understanding of the cross_validate documentation, if I pass the following (with `error_score=1`):

```py
DL = MLPRegressor(
        hidden_layer_sizes=(200, 200, 200), activation='relu', max_iter=16,
            solver='sgd', learning_rate='invscaling', power_t=0.9)

DL_CV = cross_validate(DL, df_training[predictor_cols], y=df_training[target_col], cv=None, n_jobs=1, pre_dispatch=5, return_train_score=False, return_estimator=True, error_score=1)
```

I should get the 'FitFailedWarning' message but no error. However, the training doesn't finish and instead the following error is raised:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

This therefore leads me to conclude that the error is due to the refit but I don't know what the purpose of refit is ...

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The estimator has to be fitted on each fold in order to return a score on each fold. If the model isn't fitted to the fold of the training data, then how could it score? In any case. this would likely be a better question for [datascience.se]

Comment: Thanks @G.Anderson. I've reworded it to hopefully make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Best model is chosen according to cv scores (on n-1 folders each time), and then refitted on the full dataset (all n folds). The reason for this refit: the more data a model  (with best params) see, the better it generalizes. And of course refitted model will have a predict method.

Comment: And you're mixing docs for 2 different classes. In cases like this the best way to resolve your concerns is to go though source code https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/aa4a10dbfaee9fd52af06f0f0c8e8ae77f243ef6/sklearn/utils/tests/test_pprint.py#L63.

Comment: Thanks for you comments @SergeyBushmanov, my question was in fact about the cross_validate class where there is only one set of hyperparameters. I've edited my question to improve the clarity.

Comment: You need to check your data for nans and infs

Comment: hi @SergeyBushmanov thanks for your suggestion but I know for a fact that it's not to do with the data. I've updated the question to reflect this. Furthermore, regardless of my data, the documentation mentions refits and I'm unable to find a reason why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cross_validate` does not refit, as you can verify from the source code.  The documentation is incorrect, presumably having been copied from that of `GridSearchCV`.  You should open an Issue or make a pull request; if you'd rather not, I can.

I don't know the source of your final error though; perhaps the error gets raised while scoring a successfully fit model, rather than during fitting?  If the original fit only raises a warning, then that won't get caught by default in the search.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense! I'll open an issue tomorrow. Thanks Ben!